# Override FormView Templates

Tags: asp.net, formview

By default the FormView control creates html like :

```
ID <asp:TextBox ID="IdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
<br />
Name <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") />
```

I prefer:

```
<ol class="form-layout">
  <li><asp:Label AssociatedControl="IdTextBox" runat="server">ID:</aspLabel><asp
  ....
</ol>
```

My plan is to create a new control ( OrderedListFormView ) that inherits the FormView and overrides the method that generates the default "crap" html.  I have been unable to find the method.  Can anyone help? Do you have a better solution that costs $0 dollars?

I would prefer to change the default behavior at design time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sound like you have the ASP.NET form blues.  Have you tried [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)?  It gives you far better control of your rendered HTML, and you can [mix it in with existing ASP.NET applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx).

Comment: Not what I initially wanted. Piss on it. This saved more time in long run.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Control Adapters to change the rendered HTML from a FormView, there is a tool kit and are pretty easy to code

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/08/CSS-Control-Adapter-Toolkit-Update.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx

Comment: I would like to change behavior at design time.

Comment: At design time you don't see the rendered HTML of the formview unless you run and when that is done the control adapter will kick in altering the rendered html